# Can I create a javascript array function array.method()

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

As told in the Douglas JavaScript good parts, I tried to create a array method as below,

```
Array.method('reduce', function (f, value) {

});
```

but I am getting

> Uncaught TypeError: Array.method is not a function
>       at :1:7

Answer (score 1):

There is no `method()` in the `Array`.
In **Douglas Crockford's** posts, he have created that method himself and then uses it.

This is the code

```
Object.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the section titled "A Simple Testing Ground" on page 20:

> Throughout the book, a method method is used to define new methods.
>   This is its definition:
>
> ```
> Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
>   this.prototype[name] = func;
>   return this;
> };
> ```
>
> It will be explained in Chapter 4.